# JMeter giving response message as "Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException/Non HTTP response message: Connection reset"

Tags: http, jmeter, http-post

I am new to JMeter and trying to send HTTP request and an email using JMeter and SMTP.

I am getting JMeter error as Non HTTP response code:

`java.net.SocketException/Non HTTP response message: Connection reset`

and SMTP error as 500/

```
Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.1and1.com, port: 587
```

[image: HTTP Header Manager Screenshot]

[image: Registration API request screenshot]

[image: View Result Tree Screenshot]

I have done the following settings:

user.properties:

```
httpclient4.retrycount=1
hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters
```

hc.parameters :

```
http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true
```

These changes still didn't solve my problem. Can you please help that where should I have to change the setting to fix this.

Comment: Could you add an screenshot of your test plan and requests?

Comment: hi @VadimYangunaev i have attached the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection settings, if you are testing from a proxy, you need to specify your proxy server host and port to JMeter.

Run the `jmeter[.bat]` file from a command line with the following parameters:

> -H [proxy server hostname or ip address]
>   -P [proxy server port]
>   -N [nonproxy hosts] (e.g. *.apache.org|localhost)
>   -u [username for proxy authentication - if required]
>   -a [password for proxy authentication - if required]

Example:

```
jmeter -H my.proxy.server -P 8000 -u username -a password -N localhost
```

Check this for more information:
[JMeter proxy server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)

Comment: this solution is not related to my issue still tried this but nothing changed.